# How I Highlight my word in JavaScript? The Word is inside the text of p that is inside in div with class name highlight_content?

Tags: html

```
var  ele212 = iframeDoc.getElementsByClassName('highlight_content')[0].children[0].getElementsByTagName('p')[3].getElementsByTagName('text')[0];
var gt=ele212.getBoundingClientRect(); 
<div class="highlight_content">
  <p>
    <text>You will see a clear and comprehensive search, filter and sort features giving users the ability to:</text>
  </p>
</div>
```

But this give the coordinates of `div` but I want the coordinate of only "You will".
How I do this ?

Comment: Please format your question's title and give more context to your question. Is it about highlighting or doing something with coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<mark>` tag to highlight the text like below

```
<text><mark>You will</mark> see a clear and comprehensive search, filter and sort features giving users the ability to:</text>
```

or

you can use `<span>` tag with class name or inline style with background color to highlight the text

```
<text><span class="highlight_content">You will</span> see a clear and comprehensive search, filter and sort features giving users the ability to:</text>

<text><span style="background-color: #FFFF00">You will</span> see a clear and comprehensive search, filter and sort features giving users the ability to:</text>
```

Comment: I want the solution without inseting the tag.I want the solution such that when user select the text that time they will highlight .Can you solve this using getSelection() , createRange() etc methods.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/Bilalchk123/1o4j0w2v/ for highlight and remove highlighted text